# Different definitions of calculating Pressure from stress tensor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

We usually calculate the pressure from stress tensor by

$\displaystyle p=-\frac{1}{3}\sigma_{ii}=-\frac{1}{3}(\sigma_{xx}+\sigma_{yy}+\sigma_{zz})$

However, we know the well-known wikipedia page about Cauchy stress tensor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor

It has another definition of pressure as follows:

$\displaystyle p=\lambda\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}-\frac{1}{3}\sigma_{ii}=\lambda\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}-\frac{1}{3}\sigma_{ii}$

where $\mathbf{u}$ is velocity.

How to understand these two different definitions of pressure using stress tensors?

For me, it is like the 1st equation is for a static object, while the $2^{nd}$ equation is for a dynamic object.

Comment: Yes. It's that simple. In elasticity theory (the context of the first definition), static conditions are typically assumed.

Comment: Yes, my work is based on elasticity assumption.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to whether we consider the fluid incompressible or not.  If the fluid is considered incompressible, then the pressure is not determinate from the equilibrium equation of state of the fluid, the continuity terms contributing to the isotropic part of the stress tensor are zero, and we need to determine the pressure from the equations of motion, the incompressible Newtonian constitutive equation, and the boundary conditions.

But if the fluid is not incompressible, then what we call the pressure is the value calculated from the equilibrium equation of state, and it doesn't comprise the totality of minus the isotropic part of the stress tensor.  There are also viscous contributions to the isotropic part of the stress tensor